# Looping a whole lot of jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have 20 experiments with 3 buttons in each of them. As I click on each button, I get a set of image slides. Now I can do this for one experiment which involves 3 functions for the 3 buttons in that experiment.

I need to do this for 20 such experiments, but to continue doing it this way for all the 20 experiments, I'll need 60 functions, which is unreasonable.

Here's the code for one such button event.

HTML:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#container1").hide();
    $("#container2").hide();
    $("#container3").hide();
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>    
     <a id="a_exp1" href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration:none;    color:black;">
    <div>
     <img src="listIm_1.png">
     <h5>AQUA HUNTER</h5>
     <p>Can you make a magnet fetch fish for you?</p></br><hr>
     </div>
     </a>
     </div>
     <audio id="button">
     <source src="button.wav" type="audio/wav"/>

      </audio>
     </body>

    <div id="container1" >
    <div id="slider1" >
        <ul>
            <li><img id="Img" src='slide_intro.png'/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $("a").click(function(){
        var exp_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(exp_id == "a_exp1"){                     
            $("#right").html("<div><img id='myimage1' onclick='changeimage1()'   src='build_i.png'/><img id='myimage2' onclick='changeimage2()' src='apply_i.png'/><img id='myimage3' onclick='changeimage3()' src='learn_i.png'/></div>")
        }
    });
});
    function changeimage1()
    { $("#nextBtn").remove();
      $("#prevBtn").remove();
      $("#PicInRightTitle").css({'visibility':'hidden'});    
      $("#container2").hide();
      $("#container3").hide();
      $("#container1").show();
      $("#slider").easySlider({       
          auto: false, 
          continuous: true
      });

      document.getElementById('button').play();
      cc=0;
      if (cc==0) 
      {
          cc=1;
          document.getElementById('myimage1').src="build_a.png";
          document.getElementById('myimage2').src="apply_i.png";
          document.getElementById('myimage3').src="learn_i.png";
      }
    }
```

Now, in this function there are a few lines specific to this one button click, and a few can be applied to all 60 functions. How can I simplify this? How do I loop it into one function?

Comment: Can you paste all the relevant HTML pls? where all the items, that are called in jQuery are shown so that we can see the structure.

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs, and navigation functions like `closest()` and `find()` to find the related elements that need to be manipulated. It's hard to tell the overall structure of your application from what you've shown.

Comment: priyanka, if the changes are with respect to just css then i guess you can make them all be in a single file and apply appropriate class on conditional basis(depending on your experiments)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.@Zim84-I have added the relevant HTML for one button.I have 3 sets of slides for the 3 buttons in one experiment, which explains the hide statement for container1 and 2.  @Barmar- Thanks for the suggestion, ill try and use it.

Comment: @dreamweiver- This involves CSS as well as a whole lot of JS, it need to call these functions on each button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChangeImage () {}

ChangeImage.prototype.action = function () {
    console.log('do some common things');
}

var ChangeImageTwo = function () {
    this.action = function () {
        console.log('do some unique things');
        ChangeImageTwo.prototype.action.call();
        console.log('do some more unique things');
    }
}

ChangeImageTwo.prototype = new ChangeImage;

new ChangeImageTwo().action();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/rnxjk/)

Comment: Oh thank you! Quite new to this, so ill have to try understanding how this works first before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rethink your js and structure.

You need just one function, plus the binding of just one event on the whole set of buttons.

**Rough idea**

The first step is the mapping from button to the set of pictures.
A naive approach can be an associative array or an object literal.

```
var buttonToImages = {
     "a_exp1" : ['build_a.png', 'apply_i.png', 'learn_i.png'],
     "a_exp2" : ['build_a2.png', 'apply_i2.png', 'learn_i2.png']
     //and so on...
}
```

Then you can bind to each anchor a generic listener. You can avoid to create for each click the div with the three images: you can manipulate static html at click time.

```
$("a").each(function(i, anchor){
         var images = buttonToImages[anchor.attr("id")];
         anchor.click(function(){
              $('myimage1').attr("src")=images[0];
              $('myimage2').attr("src")=images[1];
              $('myimage3').attr("src")=images[2];
         });
});
```

This will initialize the three images when you click on the experiment buttons.

Then, if you have to cycle on the images when you click on the image itself.
It's not clear from your problem which is the logic behind the images: if you can rely on some naming convention it's easy to manipulate the source with a single listener.

If there is no naming convention, you can change the buttonToImages dictionary and list there the sequence of images for each tag img.

I cannot add comment yet, so I will be more precise if you'll find useful this indications